# R spatial: Erase one polygon from another: correct use of `st_difference`?

Tags: gdal, r, overlapping-features, sp, rgdal

I am trying to erase one shapefile from the other, similar to ArcGIS **Erase tool**: [image]

This worked pretty well with `rgeos::gDifference(spdf1, spdf2)`, which needs as input geometry of SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

Now, I want to switch from SPDF files to `sf` or `sfc` objects. But, `st_difference` does not keep a not overlapping geometry. Instead, it keeps `buffer minus one` :

Instead, I want to keep part encircled in blue: 
[image]

How to correctly **Erase** features using `sf` objects? I tried tools `st_difference`, `st_sym_difference` or using features `st_geometry(sf)` for operation, but I get to have the same, for me unwanted results. Also, I found a suggestion of [st_erase function](https://rdrr.io/cran/sf/man/geos_binary_ops.html):

```
st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y)))
```

But using it on my data `erased <- st_erase(buff, u)` generates error:

```
`Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y))   Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point`
```

Here is my example:

```
# Load data
shp = system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")

my.sf <- st_read(shp, quiet = TRUE)

# Convert crs to projected system to make buffer
my.sf.web<- st_transform(my.sf, 3857)

# Subset the data to create two independent shps
i = 10

# Split datasets in two files
one  = my.sf.web[i, ]
left = my.sf.web[-i,]

# Create buffer 
buff = st_buffer(one, 35000 ) # distance


# CHeck which polygons overlaps with my buffer
out.overlap = st_overlaps(buff, left)


# Subset the polygons that overlaps with the buffer
nbrs.buff <- left[st_overlaps(buff,left)[[1]],]


u <- st_union(st_geometry(nbrs.buff), st_geometry(one), by_feature = FALSE)
#u <- st_union(st_combine(st_geometry(nbrs.buff)), 
 #             st_combine(st_geometry(one)))
int.buff.one = st_difference(buff, u)   # NOT WORKING HERE???
```

Comment: I don't understand what `u` is meant to be here. Each feature is the combination of the source feature and the feature you buffered. That is complicating the difference situation. `plot(st_geometry(st_difference(buff, st_union(u))))` seems to extract the bit of the buffer above `u` but I'm not sure the way you construct `u` makes sense in the first place...

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, the `u` should just spatially merge my first geometry `one` and it's neighbors `nbrs.buff` and create single file. So, I just simply want to erase `u` from the `buffer`. Thanks, `plot(st_geometry(st_difference(buff, st_union(u))))` makes correctly erase `u` from `buff`. Do you think I should rerun 
 union tool `u2 <- st_union(u)` to have correct output? Or how would you simplify the union operation?

Comment: If you want to add a feature back to a spatial data frame, `rbind`: `uu = rbind(nbrs.buff, one)`.

Comment: Have you checked if either u or buff have self-intersection problems?

Comment: @Mox, great idea!! I don't know how to check for self-intersection problems, but I am sure that they do, as the `one` vertices completely overlaps with vertices in `nbrs.buff`, as I `one` was to `nbrs.buff` geometry!!! when I create `u = st_union(rbind(nbrs.buff, one))` (as suggested by @Spacedman) and then run `st_difference()` it creates correct output! I'll test `st_dissolve` and  `st_combine` to see which one is more appropriate to run.

Comment: seems that `st_union(u)` should be enought to dissolve inner boundaries between individul polygons in `nbrs.buff' and run `st_difference`. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 7):

Your code worked just fine for me, so I think that make it throws that error because you have some topology error in your shape. I've just adapted your code adding a check and repair part in order to avoid error (*st_is_valid* and *st_make_valid*).

[Here you can download the data and code I've used](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lBbhbEn85fsgXaVMmzU8Rc2kOLyPvJse?usp=sharing).

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

# Load data
my.sf <- st_read("shape/shape.gpkg", quiet = TRUE)

# Check for errors
st_is_valid(my.sf, reason = TRUE)

# Repare if needed
my.sf <- st_make_valid(my.sf)

# Subset the data to create two independent shps
i = 2
one  = my.sf[i, ]
left = my.sf[-i,]

# Create buffer 
buff = st_buffer(one, 1000) # distance

# CHeck which polygons overlaps with my buffer
out.overlap = st_overlaps(buff, left)

# Subset the polygons that overlaps with the buffer
nbrs.buff <- left[st_overlaps(buff,left)[[1]],]

u <- st_union(st_geometry(nbrs.buff), st_geometry(one), by_feature = FALSE)

int.buff.one = st_difference(buff, u) 

# RESULTS
mapview(my.sf)+mapview(int.buff.one, alpha=0.5, color="red",lwd=3)
```

[image]